# ID4 ADFS 3.0 and oidc-client (vue spa) - Callback implementation

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect, adfs3.0, oidc-client-js

To add ADFS 3.0 authentication in our SPA we use the javascript [sample](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.0/quickstarts/6_javascript_client.html) and one (wsfed) [external identityprovider](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.0/topics/signin_external_providers.html), and we also add a [local api](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.0/topics/add_apis.html) for the SPA client

We also added a custom view to the login process, where the user could "Select WorkingContext" and we could set an additional claim.

**Problem: How to add and retrive that additional claim?**

Since we simply need the a few of the claim from ws federation, we've made a super simple `callback` where we just do the following (I'm answering the [questions from the docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.0/topics/signin_external_providers.html#handling-the-callback-and-signing-in-the-user))

Handling the callback and signing in the user

1. inspect the identity returned by the external provider.

   - Yes, we get correct claims from wsfed
2. make a decision how you want to deal with that user. This might be different based on the fact if this is a new user or a returning user. New users might need additional steps and UI before they are allowed 
   in.

   - No additional steps required
3. probably create a new internal user account that is linked to the external provider.

   - No, we don't need the user, we just need the a few of the claims from wsfed, so we just return a TestUser based on the wsfed sub in  `FindUserFromExternalProvider`
4. store the external claims that you want to keep.

   - Do we need to store the claims, will the claims not be embedded in the jwt token, and the token simply validated?
5. delete the temporary cookie

   - ok
6. sign-in the user

   - Here we would like to show a custom ui where the user should select a "workingcontext", and we could add the "workingcontext" as an additional claim.

Assuming the above is valid, how can we in step 6 add the extra claim?

`await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(provider, providerUserId, user.SubjectId, user.Username, true, context?.ClientId));`
 doesn't seem to give any ways to add claims.

This is how we try to pass the additional claims through the login process:

```
    var isuser = new IdentityServerUser(user.SubjectId)
            {
                DisplayName = user.Username,
                IdentityProvider = provider,
                AdditionalClaims = additionalLocalClaims
            };


            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, localSignInProps);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just need to implement the `IProfileService`, that's all.